# Conflict dependency Eclipse Mars & WSO2 APIM tools plugin

Tags: eclipse, wso2, eclipse-mars

I just installed the Eclipse Mars IDE and the WSO2 APIM tooling plugin.

Be careful, there is an error on the URL of the plugin present in page https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Installing+the+API+Manager+Tooling+Plug-In. The version number of API Manager in 2.0.0 instead of 2.1.0.

Conflict dependency are identified blocking the installation of the plugin
What is the workaround? Installing an older version of the plugin and the IDE?

```
Eclipse Version: March 4.5.0 buildId = 20150621-1200
Version of the WSO2 plugin: 2.1.0.201611241214
```

Eclipse Logs:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: WSO2 API Manager Tooling Feature 2.1.0.201611241214 (org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.apim.feature.feature.group 2.1.0.201611241214)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.5.0.20150621-1200 (epp.package.java 4.5.0.20150621-1200)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core Resource Management 3.10.0.v20150423-0755 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.10.0.v20150423-0755)
    Core Resource Management 3.10.1.v20150725-1910 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.10.1.v20150725-1910)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.5.0.20150621-1200 (epp.package.java 4.5.0.20150621-1200)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature.feature.group [4.5.0.20150621-1200]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EPP Java Package 4.5.0.20150621-1200 (org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature.feature.group 4.5.0.20150621-1200)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.5.0.v20150603-2358 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.5.0.v20150603-2358)
    To: org.eclipse.core.resources [3.10.0.v20150423-0755]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WSO2 API Manager Tooling Feature 2.1.0.201611241214 (org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.apim.feature.feature.group 2.1.0.201611241214)
    To: org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.registry.apim.perspective [2.1.0.201611241214]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: KernelLibraries 4.1.0.201604061411 (org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.kernel.libraries 4.1.0.201604061411)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.resources 3.10.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Perspective 2.1.0.201611241214 (org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.registry.apim.perspective 2.1.0.201611241214)
    To: bundle org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.kernel.libraries 4.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you are trying to install requires Eclipse 4.5.2 as a minimum.

Since you have 4.5.0 you should be able to 'Help > Check for Updates' to update to 4.5.2

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just installed the latest version of Eclipse via the installer, Neon 4.6.2. Ok for the installation of the APIM-Tools plugin.